# rawValue ++max is deprecated swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this problem I can not solve. paste my code

```
static let count: Int = {
    var max: Int = 0
    while let _ = PDFList(rawValue: ++max) {}
    return max
}()
```

}

I tried to write this but it does not work

```
rawValue: (max += 1)) {}
```

if you help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+=` is not an expression like `++`, it's a statement. That is, it doesn't evaluate to a value that can be used in assignment, as a parameter, etc.

You have to split it apart, then use `max` directly:

```
static let count: Int = {
    var max = 0
    while let _ = PDFList(rawValue: max) { max += 1 }
    return max
}()
```

This is more clear, IMO:

```
static let count: Int = {
    var max = 0
    while PDFList(rawValue: max) != nil { max += 1 }
    return max
}()
```

Comment: Note that this is slightly different from the original code which never checks `rawValue` with the value `0`, therefore you should start with `max = 1`. Exactly the reason why `++` has been deprecated - it's difficult to see the edge cases.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, thanks for pointing that out. This was intentional, as I presume it was a bug in the original. I forgot to mention that I made this change, though, so good on ya

Answer (score 1):

The functional way to do this is:

```
static let count: Int = {
   let max = (1 ... Int.max)
      .first { PDFList(rawValue: $0) == nil }
   return max!
}()
```

The original code never checks `0` and I am not sure whether that's correct. If it's not correct, change the lower bound of the range to `0`.